# Use custom logger in global validators

Tags: nestjs

new to nestJS world here,
I'm trying to use my custom Logger I already use inside my nest application.

This is the code that I use to create the application

```
async function bootstrap() {
  try {
    const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule, {
      bufferLogs: true,
    });

    const logger = app.get(CustomLogger);
    app.useLogger(logger);
    app.useGlobalPipes(new CustomValidationPipe());
}
```

How can I use my custom logger inside my CustomValidationPipe?

Answer (score 0):

To use your custom logger inside your CustomValidationPipe, you could inject the custom logger as a constructor parameter in the CustomValidationPipe class. In your AppModule, you would add the custom logger as a provider and make it available for injection. Here's an example:

```
@Injectable()
export class CustomValidationPipe implements PipeTransform {
  constructor(private readonly logger: CustomLogger) {}

  transform(value: any, metadata: ArgumentMetadata) {
    // Use the logger inside your pipe implementation here.
    this.logger.log(`Value being transformed: ${value}`);
    ...
  }
}

@Module({
  providers: [CustomValidationPipe, CustomLogger],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

And in your bootstrap function, you can continue to use your custom logger as shown in your code:

```
async function bootstrap() {
  try {
    const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule, {
      bufferLogs: true,
    });

    const logger = app.get(CustomLogger);
    app.useLogger(logger);
    app.useGlobalPipes(new CustomValidationPipe());
  } catch (error) {
    ...
  }
}
```

This way, your custom logger will be available for use inside your CustomValidationPipe.

Comment: Thanks for your help, very appreciated. But doing this way shouldn't I get an error here: app.useGlobalPipes(new CustomValidationPipe()); because I'm not passing the parameter to the CustomValidationPipe constructor ?